# Wordpress developer api php curl create new post issue

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

Hi please help me for this issue for creating new post form from php code.

```
$access_token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$post = array('title=Hello World','content=Hello. I am a test post. I was created by the API','date='.date('YmdHis'),'categories=API','tags=tests');
$post = urlencode(implode('&',$post));
$apicall = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/MYSITEID/posts/new";
$ch = curl_init($apicall);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($return);
exit;
```

Its results as:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","message":"That API call is not allowed for this account."}
```

is there any mistake in code.
 I have checked this in api console. https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/ its working but in code its not working

Comment: Check your permissions in the developer account where u create this access token

Comment: its author and its working console and as reference site http://onlywire.com site also. but not working in code

Comment: There may be some authentication problem, please check all setting carefully

Comment: The whole thing i did as per document for api..
anyway thanks waiting for any issue or bug from someone

Answer (score 0):

They way you are preparing the `$post` data is totally wrong. You are making `url-encode` over the whole content and that's why API server didn't able to recognize the content.

Replace your `$post` with this one:

```
$post = array(
    'title'=>'Hello World',
    'content'=>'Hello. I am a test post. I was created by the API',
    'date'=>date('YmdHis'),
    'categories'=>'API','tags=tests'
);
$post = http_build_query($post);
```

The function `http_build_query` will automatically do the `url-encode` over the content from the `$post` array.

Comment: @user2706194 Please update the code with my sugegsted code in your question. Also run the code with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` and it will show you curl's output. Please include that output into the question description as well. Also, make sure your authorization token is a valid one.

Comment: @user2706194 another thing, is `Authorization` not `authorization`. Notice the capital `A` and change it in your code as well.

Comment: yes thats working thanks, can you tell me reason behind this result : 
{"error":"unauthorized","message":"User cannot publish posts"} after this change